# How do you add a backend when uploading a React Native App to the IOS App Store?

Tags: ios, node.js, react-native, expo, app-store

I want to know how to add a backend when uploading a React Native App to the IOS App Store?

EXPO has:

```
eas build --platform ios
```

However, I believe that this command is run from the React Native Mobile App folder..
This creates a build. However, the backend/server is completely left out which is needed for the app to function. How do I include the backend into the build that is uploaded to Expo. Or otherwise how do I also upload the backend to Expo or the IOS mobile App Platform along with the React Native Front End Build?

My folder structure is as follows for my React Native App:
server (backend)
client (frontend)

Answer (score 0):

You don't. You deploy the backend separately and call it from your app.

If you only need a "local" backend - i.e., no login, no data needs to be available to you as the app developer or users from each other - you can use built-in storage and persistence.